# Bootsrap3 issue on largest screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, screen-resolution

I have an image at the bottom of my webpage that is set to width:100% which when I have the body-content section of my _layout page set to 80% then they line up on all screen sizes including:

- 240 x 340
- 320 x 480
- 640 x 480
- 800 x 600
- 1024 x 600
- 1024 x 768
- 1280 x 800
- 1280 x 1024
- 1366 x 768

However when using large screens with a resolution of 1920 x 1024 then the image at the bottom is being set much wider than the body-content, what would be causing this? Do I have to write specific media queries for this screensize in the bootstrap css?

You can see an example of this by going to www.testsize.com and entering the following URL http://budgetonlinebill.azurewebsites.net/

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Budget Energy</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <div id="pgBottomGraphicHolder">
    <img src="~/Images/bottomGraphic.gif" style="width:100%">
  </div>
```

Comment: What classes are you using on the image?

Comment: I have updated the code to show my html

Comment: The problem was due to the bootstrap containers max width being set to 1170px, I fixed this by adding another bit of css for larger screen @media (min-width: 1920px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }

Comment: Nice one. You can answer your own question and mark it resolved :)